# I want to add products to the shopping cart in PHP

Tags: php, shopping-cart

When i click on adding a product to the shopping cart it shows me this: ' 1 = 0 ' and no product name nor price etc... can anyone please help? (i should mention that the init.inc file has the DB connection that works)

This is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Start the session
require_once 'inc/init.inc.php';


// check if the cart array exists in the session, if not create it
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// check if the product has been added to cart
if (isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    // get product details
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    // create an array of product data
    $product_data = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'product_name' => $product_name,
        'price' => $price,
        'quantity' => $quantity
    );

    // add product data to cart array
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = $product_data;
}



?>
```

AND THIS :

```
<div class="text-dark">
    <?php
    // display cart items
    if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        echo "Your cart is empty";
    } else {
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
            echo "<p class=\"text-dark\">" . $product['product_name'] . "  " . $product['quantity'] . " = " . floatval($product['price']) * intval($product['quantity']) . "</p>";

        }
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

I am starting the session here:

```
<?php

// 1. connecting to DB

$pdoBlog = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;
        dbname=onye',
        'root',
        'root',
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',

        )
    );
// 2. starting a session
session_start();

//3 . a variableto show the messages(error or success)
$contenu = '';
/* this variable will be exclusively used to show the errors and the success messages, we leave it empty and concatenate it with:  .=  to show the messages*/
    

//4. including the functions.php file

require_once 'functions.inc.php';
```

And this is not working:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
    echo "<p class=\"text-dark\">" . 
        $product['product_name'] . "  " . 
        $product['quantity'] . " = " .
        number_format(floatval($product['price']), 2) * intval($product['quantity']) . 
        "</p>";
```

as I want it to display the product_name etc... not only 1=0 1 being the quantity. I have moved things around and tried calling the variables differently.

And this is the $_POST form for the product for add to cart:

```
    <form method="POST" action="cart.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $_GET["product_id"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $_GET["product_name"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $_GET["price"]; ?>">
        <label>Quantity: </label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1">
        <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart">Add to Cart
            <?php
            // Get the number of items in the cart
            $cart_count = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0;

            // Display the cart count
            echo "($cart_count)";
            ?>
        </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where do you [`start_session()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: _"and no product name nor price etc"_ - you are trying to take those values from $_POST, but we have currently no idea what data your are actually _sending_.

Comment: If you are getting `1 = 0` as output in your list there, then that would probably mean that _only_ a quantity of 1 was send via the POST request, but none of the other parameters. (Or the price was not actually in a format PHP understands as a float.) And the _price_ should rather not be send from the frontend to begin with - otherwise it would be no problem for the user to manipulate that value. Setting the price to 0 would mean I get stuff from you or free - and if I set it to -500, _you_ would actually owe _me_ money now :-)

Comment: format the result not part of the calc `number_format(floatval($product['price']) * intval($product['quantity']),2)`

Comment: `echo $cart_count;` quotes and brackets are not needed

Comment: getting the product_name to show on the cart page would be great ... still not getting it :( it's been two days i'm on this...

Comment: There are many moving parts in your code. It's hard to get a simple answer here if the question involves too many thing. Try to use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump) or [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) + [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r) to examine important variables on every steps. Compare the output to your expectation. Try to narrow down the specific issue on any unexpected result. If you can't fix those already, then ask concrete question about it here.